# how to get back up of all phone data after Flash stock ROM?

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, data-recovery

i am having Letv 2 mobile phone, unfortunately i uninstall google launcher and my phone stop working. i was advised to update system and my all phone data has been lost. i want all phone data back, please help me how do i get it back?

Comment: What data do you mean? Contacts? Music? SMS? or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest not writing any new file on your device until the deleted ones get recovered. You can use tools like Wondershare Dr. Fone for android(Its a PC app) https://drfone.wondershare.net/android-data-recovery.html. Its paid but you can try it for free if it works or not for you. Another tool I remember is Disk Digger(Android app) and its pro version Disk Digger Pro which requires root access. If they dont work you may need to seek professional help. But remember dont write new files on your phone as they would overwrite the deleted ones and make them unrecoverable.